# Ninject generic type xml binding

Tags: c#, xml, generics, ninject

I need to bind generic interface with generic implementation using Ninject.Extensions.Xml. The project is .net mvc project. Is there any way to accomplish this ?

The class:

```
public class JsonProvider<T> : IJsonProvider<T> where T: new()
{
    ...
}
```

Xml configuration (Not working):

```
<bind service="Base.IJsonProvider, Base" to="Base.JsonProvider, Base"
   name ="Config"/>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use this using XML? Configuration of DI structure using XML is fragile, verbose and error prone. Consider using code-first registrations instead, and for everything that actually needs to change after deployment, only put configuration switches in your configuration file, instead of using the fully qualified names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to bind open generic types, so this type definition should do the trick:

```
<bind service="Base.IJsonProvider`1, Base" to="Base.JsonProvider`1, Base" 
    name ="Config"/>
```

Comment: It gives the error: Couldn't resolve type 'Base.IJsonProvider`1[T], Base' defined in 'service' attribute.

Comment: There is mixed information that I find on the web, please try the updated answer (type declarations without `[T]`)